# What happens when I use a battery with too much current?

Tags: current

I am working on creating a line-bot from a book and it calls for a 6v, 1AH battery. I have these [NiMh AA batteries](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000J47L) that are rated at 2.3AH, 1.2v. Is there a way to set these up safely for the bot? What happens if I use too much current but the correct voltage?

Comment: You mean a 1000 mAh battery right?

Comment: Yes! Actually the book made an error there too. Supposed to be Mah

Comment: the AH rating of the battery tells you what its capacity is.  I.e. how long it will last for a given load.  The idea is that a 100mAH battery will supply 1mA for 100 hours, a 200mAH battery will supply 1mA for 200 hours, etc.  The actual amount of power you get out of a battery is a bit more complicated, but the idea is the more AH/mAH it has, the longer it will last

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to connect in series 5 of those AAs to reach 6V. You should be fine with your 2.3 Ah batteries. The Ah rating is a measurement of the battery capacity. So your AAs can deliver 2.3 amps for 1 hour. It has nothing to do with how much current the battery actually supplies to the robot.

Answer (score 4):

You would require five of the 1.2 volt Ni Mh batteries to produce 6 volts for your line-bot.  The set of 2.3 AH (or 2300 mAH) batteries would run your line-bot about 2.3 times as long as the 1 AH (or 1000 mAH) batteries.  (note that 1 AH = 1000 mAH)

As mentioned by others, the AH rating of a battery is an indication of the energy available from the battery.  Your load will only draw the current it requires, regardless of the AH rating of the battery (providing the battery voltage is correct for the load).

Answer (score 1):

the 1000mah is just how much "juice" is in the battery....if you use one that is higher....you project will run longer...it will not hurt it.